# When I Run the Code it gives fatal error & java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OnClick(View)

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

```
package com.vogella.android.temperatureconverter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputValue);

    }

    // this method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
    // "OnClick" property of the button
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
                if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
                    text.setText(String
                            .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheittoCelsius(inputValue)));
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
                    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    text.setText(String
                            .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiustoFahrenheit(inputValue)));
                    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                }
                break;
        }
    }}
```

and my xml is :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/myColor">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/celsius" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fahrenheit" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/calc"
        android:onClick="OnClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The project is compiling but when i run this it gives me "Unfortunately you application is stopped" error and on the log it givesrun time error:
Fatal Exception and  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OnClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button1'

Comment: "OnClick" is not the same as "onClick"

Comment: Solved Thanks @m02ph3u5